# android setOnInfoWindowClickListener - pass more values

Tags: android, google-maps, onclicklistener

I am using a Google map in my android app with many markers. After clicking the marker the title is showing. But I need after clicking that title to open a new activity with more values - that will show up in a textview.

My current solution now works, but it opens everytime the same info - passes the values from the last item if I click any marker. I need each marker to pass it's values.

```
    void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray actors = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

    for (int i = 0; i < actors.length(); i++) {
        final JSONObject c = actors.getJSONObject(i);

        final double g1 = Double.parseDouble(c.getString("gps1"));
        final double g2 = Double.parseDouble(c.getString("gps2"));
        LatLng poss = new LatLng(g1,g2);

        final String title = c.getString("name");
        final String place = c.getString("place");
        final String place2 = c.getString("place2");
        final String perexfull = c.getString("perexfull");
        final String img1 = c.getString("img1");
        final String info = c.getString("info");

   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(poss).title(title).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SingleitemView.class);

                intent.putExtra("place", place);
                intent.putExtra("place2", place2);
                intent.putExtra("perexfull", perexfull);
                intent.putExtra("name", title);
                intent.putExtra("img1", img1);
                intent.putExtra("info", info);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
      }
```

I also tried to put the setOnInfoWindowClickListener out of the for loop, but then the variables like place, info are not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define a MarkerInfo class, that will hold all the info for each Marker:

```
public class MarkerInfo {
    public String mTitle;
    public String mPlace;
    public String mPlace2;
    public String mPerexfull;
    public String mImg1;
    public String mInfo;

    public MarkerInfo(String title, String place, String place2, String perexfull, String img1, String info) {
        mTitle = title;
        mPlace = place;
        mPlace2 = place2;
        mPerexfull = perexfull;
        mImg1 = img1;
        mInfo = info;
    }
}
```

Then, define a HashMap as a member variable with the Marker as the key, and a MarkerInfo object as the value:

```
GoogleMap mMap;
Map<Marker, MarkerInfo> mMarkerMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, create a MarkerInfo object for each Marker, and add it to the HashMap.  Then, when an InfoWindow is clicked, retrieve the information from the corresponding MarkerInfo object:

```
void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray actors = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

    for (int i = 0; i < actors.length(); i++) {
        final JSONObject c = actors.getJSONObject(i);

        final double g1 = Double.parseDouble(c.getString("gps1"));
        final double g2 = Double.parseDouble(c.getString("gps2"));
        LatLng poss = new LatLng(g1,g2);

        final String title = c.getString("name");
        final String place = c.getString("place");
        final String place2 = c.getString("place2");
        final String perexfull = c.getString("perexfull");
        final String img1 = c.getString("img1");
        final String info = c.getString("info");

        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(poss).title(title).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));

        MarkerInfo markerInfo = new MarkerInfo(title, place, place2, perexfull, img1, info);

        mMarkerMap.put(marker, markerInfo);
    }

    //Set this only once:
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            MarkerInfo markerInfo = mMarkerMap.get(marker);


            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SingleitemView.class);

            intent.putExtra("place", markerInfo.mPlace);
            intent.putExtra("place2", markerInfo.mPlace2);
            intent.putExtra("perexfull", markerInfo.mPerexfull);
            intent.putExtra("name", markerInfo.mTitle);
            intent.putExtra("img1", markerInfo.mImg1);
            intent.putExtra("info", markerInfo.mInfo);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I did it fully correctly, but this solution finally works for me! I took the setOnInfoWindowClickListener out of the loop and then:

```
    HashMap<Marker, String> values1 = new HashMap<Marker, String>();
    HashMap<Marker, String> values2 = new HashMap<Marker, String>();

 values1.put(marker, c.getString("place"));
 values1.put(marker, c.getString("place2"));
```

and then inside of onInfoWindowClick I used:

```
   intent.putExtra("place", values1.get(marker));
            intent.putExtra("place2", values2.get(marker));
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but see my answer for a cleaner solution.  You don't need a separate HashMap for each data item.

Comment: perfect, seems better and works like a charm! thanks